# jquery .not() for closing menu (or modal) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have a menu that toggles open clicking on a button. I was asked to make it close whenever you click outside of the open menu as well.

This is practically identical to the "click outside of a modal to close it" behaviour, but applied on a fixed menu header.

I thought of something like this:

```
$('*').not('.header').on('click', function(){
        //close menu function
    console.log("close the menu")
});
```

but it's not working in many ways:

1) wherever i click, the console.log fires
2) for each click, i get 3 console.log fired.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln1wabqq/1/

I've tried changing the `$('*')` to

- `$('*:not(".header")')`
- `$('*').not('.header, .header *')`
- `$('').not('.header')`

but I get the same exact output. Am I on a totally wrong path here?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could detect a click outside element like this :

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.header').length){
        // click outside .header
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Clicks **bubble**, so by hooking `click` on every element in the document, you're hooking it on elements and their descendants/ancestors. As the click bubbles, your handler is fired at each level.

If you want to handle it by hooking on every element, you can use a handler that ignores clicks on elements that are descendants of `.header`:

```
$("*").on("click.closemenu", function() {
    if ($(this).closest(".header").length) {
        // This is .header or a descendant, ignore
    } else {
        // Close menu

        // Remove this handler (if desired)
        $("*").off("click.closemenu");
    }
    return false; // Either way, prevent further bubbling and any default action
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
       $("body :not(".header")").clicked(your function)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **.header** is a *body* direct children, try using:

```
$('body>*').not('.header').on('click', function(){
    //close menu function
    console.log("close the menu")
});
```

See the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1hoe69p/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here a way to do what you need, filtre only element wich have "header" as parent class.

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function(e){
    if ($(this).parent('.header').length > 0) {
        //close menu function
        console.log("close the menu");
    }
});
```